# collection_selectについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@tags = Tag.all
@post.taggings.build
```

上記はcontorllerのプログラムででtaggingsはpostテーブルとtagsテーブルの中間テーブルです。下記はviewです。

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.fields_for :taggings do |pt| %>
        <%= pt.collection_select :tag_id, @tags, :id, :display_name, { prompt: "選択してください", label: "タグ" }, class: "tag-fields"  %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

post(ブログの投稿)を編集するときに編集ページを開くと、その投稿に紐づくタグが表示されるのはよいのですが、新規のセレクトボックス(選択してくださいと表示されているセレクトボックス)まで表示されてしまいます。

どうすれば、関連しているタグのみ表示できるのでしょうか？それとselectとcollection_selectも違いがよく分かっていないので、その辺の使い分けもご教示いただけると助かります。

Comment: 基本的に質問はひとつに絞った方が回答が得られやすいかと思います。  
  
> それとselectとcollection_selectも違いがよく分かっていない
  
まずはリファレンスに目を通して、サンプルコードを検索して探してみると理解が深まると思います。  

http://railsdoc.com/references/select  
http://railsdoc.com/references/collection_select

Answer (score 1):

> 新規のセレクトボックス(選択してくださいと表示されているセレクトボックス)まで表示されてしまいます。

編集でも新規でも以下のコードがhtmlになってしまうため「選択してください」が表示されてしまいます。

`<%= pt.collection_select :tag_id, @tags, :id, :display_name, { prompt: "選択してください", label: "タグ" }, class: "tag-fields"  %>`

以下のようにすればうまくいくと思います。

1. セレクトボックスの先頭に空の行を追加する
2. 空の行に「選択してください」と表示する

実際のコードとしては以下のようなイメージです。

`<%= pt.collection_select :tag_id, @tags, :id, :display_name, label: "タグ" }, class: "tag-fields", include_blank: '選択してください' %>`

`include_blank` については以下でご確認ください。
http://railsdoc.com/references/collection_select

また、文字列を `erb` に直接記載するよりも `i18n` を利用する方が一般的なので、余裕があれば `i18n` について調べてみて、以下を試してみるとより良いコードになると思います、

`<%= pt.collection_select :tag_id, @tags, :id, :display_name, label: "タグ" }, class: "tag-fields", include_blank: true %>`

app_name/config/locales/ja.yml

```
ja:
  helpers:
    select:
      include_blank: "選択してください"
```